# auto completion(clt+space) in netbeans problem

Tags: html, netbeans

when i am coding at netbeans i use a lot clt+space to help me remember attributes for body, p,..
but for example bgcolor attribute for table is not showing with clt+space

```
 <table bgcolor="red">
    </table>
```

but if i use style attribute i should use background-color: aqua
the auto completion property here is working

```
  <table  style="background-color: aqua"></table>
```

can any one tell me why is that ???

Comment: Not really a question, more down to the editor your using. Perhaps better in superuser?

Comment: Well the `bgcolor` attribute was deprecated 20 years ago: [This attribute has been deprecated in favor of style sheets for specifying background color information.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor). So perhaps the NetBeans development team decided not to encourage bad practices, but that's just speculation on my part. Only the NetBeans developers can really answer your question.

Comment: is there any thing i can do to make the editor autocomplete all attributes??